# Get dataModel back from [NSArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.value"] other than just value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Here is my data model:

```
@interface DataModel : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *label;
@property (nonatomic) float value;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger index;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *unit;
@end
```

And i have a NSArray with this data model

```
NSArray *myDataModels;
```

Now i need to get a data model back from this array with the highest `@property (nonatomic) float value;`

I can get the highest value back by using

```
[[myDataModels valueForKeyPath:@"@max.value"] intValue]
```

But what i need is the whole `DataModel` with highest value, not just the value.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Once you get the maximum value, you can use NSPredicate to get the data model related to that max value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to iterate your array and find the max value.

```
DataModel *maxModel = nil;
float maxValue = FLT_MIN;
for (DataModel *model in myDataModels) {
    if (model.value > maxValue) {
        maxModel = model;
        maxValue = model.value;
    }
}

NSLog(@"The max model is %@", maxModel);
```

Comment: Yeah, using iterator can absolutely solve everything, but what i meant is just using `[NSArray valueForKeyPath:@“@max.value”]` or similar approach but as simple as this one.

Comment: I don't believe you can use KVC to get a reference to the whole object. But I'm not 100% sure of that.

Answer (score 5):

Smallest version using Predicate can be

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.value ==%@.@max.value", myDataModels];
NSArray *filteredArray = [myDataModels filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
if(filteredArray.count>0)
    DataModel *smallestValue = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Or you can do it like this as well (As @Puneet suggested in comment),

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.value == %@",[myDataModels valueForKeyPath:@"@max.value"]];
NSArray *filteredArray = [myDataModels filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
if(filteredArray.count>0)
    DataModel *smallestValue = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: is `filteredArrayUsingPredicate ` doing the second search? because i think `valueForKeyPath` already did search for one time, if i need to search twice to get a element from a array, i'd rather use iterator. But thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Actually, you can't say which method is best because it depends on many factors. For example, how many data in the you have in an array? If you are able to confirm the data size, you can perform a simple load test. You can always compare and choose. More on NSPredicate you can [ReadHere](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/) which says its a query language so probably not looping twice but still not sure of it.